# Cast from long to object

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, object, long-integer

hi am new to working with SQLite using android,i have been searching for a way to do CRUD operations using SQLite database that stores Long , while am working with User Object.
my insertDetails method is here:

```
public Long insertDetails(String fname, String lname,String sex,String birthdate) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(UserOpenHelper.FNAME, fname);
    contentValues.put(UserOpenHelper.LNAME, lname);
    contentValues.put(UserOpenHelper.SEX, sex);
    contentValues.put(UserOpenHelper.BIRTHDATE, birthdate);
    opnToWrite();
    long val = database_ob.insert(UserOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME, null,
            contentValues);


    Close();
    return val;

}
```

and i get errors in the UserActivity ,

```
List<User> values = datasource.getAllUsers();
    ArrayAdapter<User> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<User>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    User User= datasource.insertDetails(firstname, lastname, sex, birthdate);//here (1)
    adapter.add(User);
    long val = adapter.insertDetails(firstname, lastname, sex, birthdate);   //here (2)
    //long vall= adapter.insert(User, index)
    // db.addUser(new User(firstname, lastname, sex, birthdate));
    Log.d("filter", "inserted");
```

errors :

(1) -Type mismatch: cannot convert from Long to User

(2)- The method insertDetails(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type ArrayAdapter

any help please

Comment: both errors are compile time errors, it means that you don't know java basics ... 1) datasource.insertDetails  returns Long ... even if you cast it to User `User User = (User)datasource.insertDetails(...)` you will get runtime exception (ClassCastException) ... 2) `The method insertDetails(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type ArrayAdapter` means that (drums!!!) the method insertDetails(String, String, String, String) is undefined for the type ArrayAdapter (ArrayAdapter has no such method) ... so please learn some java basics before asking the question

Comment: well thanks but that didn't help , am new to java and android and that's what am doing here, finding answers for my question. everyone starts at the same point

Answer (score 0):

> (1) -Type mismatch: cannot convert from Long to User

Looking at insertDetails's signature,

```
public Long insertDetails(String, String, String, String)
```

The method returns an Object of the type Long. Since you are trying to assign it to an User object the compiler complains

```
User User= datasource.insertDetails(firstname, lastname, sex, birthdate);//here (1)
```

> (2)- The method insertDetails(String, String, String, String) is
>   undefined for the type ArrayAdapter

you are using the default implementation of `ArrayAdapter`, that does not implement the `insertDetails` method. This is why, the compiler complains

Comment: so long in the insertDetails() should be changed to User and try implementing another ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: well you could, but why you should return something that  you just create? For the second one, the answer is yes. You could subclass ArrayAdapter and implement that method

Comment: am adding users to a SQLite database, then i want to retrieve them and show them in a ListView . how can i do that in a simple way ?

Comment: in this case I would rather suggest that you take a look to: Cursor, SimpleCursorAdapter and CursorLoader. You can find a great entry point [here](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html)

Comment: my insert.xml contains editTexts firstname ,lastname ,sex,birthday, insert button and a listVeiw , when insert button is clicked i want to show the new user in the listVeiw . is that possible to manage all in one xml file ?

Comment: yes it is. Just start simple and, little by little, all the pieces will come together.